# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'... How can I solve this issue?

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I have the followig code where I am doing some interpolation but I am getting the above mentioned error in this line of code `tem=p.gamma_dB_min+p.delta_dB_gam*y`
when I run the last line of this code. could anybody solve this problem. thank you

```
def lin_interp(p,y1,yn):
    N = 28
    n = np.arange(1,N)
    y = ( [y1 + (yn-y1)/N*n], [yn] )
    tem = p.gamma_dB_min + p.delta_dB_gam*y
    gamma_dB = np.reshape(tem, [1, N*len(yn)])
    return gamma_dB

v1=y_test[1:]
v2=y_pred[1:]
gamma_DRNN1=[y_pred[1],lin_interp(p,v1,v2)]
```

I am trying to convert the following MATLAB code into python:

```
%matlab 

function [gamma_dB] = lin_interp(p,Y1,YN)
N=28;
n=(1:(N-1)).';
y=[(YN-Y1)/N.*n+Y1;YN];

gamma_dB=reshape(p.gamma_dB_min+p.delta_dB_gam*y,[1,N*length(YN)]);    

end


v1=YTest(1:(end-1));
v2=YPred(2:end);
gamma_DRNN1=[YPred(1),lin_interp(p,v1,v2)];
```

Comment: Are you trying to sum a number and a tuple? (e.g. it's not possible to do 1 + (2, 3))

Comment: I know.. but how to solve this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. What are those elements you are summing? Do you need the first element of the tuple? In that case use `[0]`. I really can't help you if you're not more specific about your data

Comment: p.gamma_dB_min & p.delta_dB_gam are two different integer values and y is given above.

Comment: `y` is a tuple. When you do `p.delta_dB_gam*y` you're making a new tuple that is `p.delta_dB_gam` times the original one (e.g. `3*(1,1)==(1,1,1,1,1,1)`). Than you are trying to sum to that tuple an integer, which just makes no sense. Think of what is your goal and than change that line accordingly

Comment: Please edit your question adding there this important information (the matlab code you are trying to translate)

Comment: yeah I updated the post. please check it the above post again. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well from the error message, its becuase `p.gamma_dB_min` is an `int` and `p.delta_dB_gam*y` is a `tuple` (or vice-versa), and this opperation is unsupported e.g. you can't do `1 + (1, )`, but you can do 1+ (1).

Make sure `p.gamma_dB_min` & `p.delta_dB_gam*y` are in the form you expect. Beyond that, it's hard to debug based on the information you provided.

Comment: p.gamma_dB_min & p.delta_dB_gam are two different integer values and y is given above.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, this is because `p.gamma_dB_min` is an int and `p.delta_dB_gam*y` is a tuple, and adding an int to a tuple is not a supported operation in Python. If what you are trying to do is add a number to *each element* of a tuple, you can use Python's `map()` function, for example:

```py
my_number = 7
my_tuple = (1,2,3,4)
result = tuple(map(lambda n: n+my_number, my_tuple))
# Giving result = (8,9,10,11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create NumPy arrays wherever you deal with more than one value. Using NumPy arrays will make your code more similar to the MATLAB code, and thus will make translation easier. In particular,

```matlab
y = [(YN-Y1)/N.*n+Y1; YN];
```

would be translated to Python as

```py
y = np.array([(YN-Y1)/N*n+Y1, YN])
```

---

Edit: It seems that `n` is an array already, the MATLAB code is concatenating. I guess the proper translation of this line is:

```py
y = np.concatenate(((YN-Y1)/N*n+Y1, np.array([YN])))
```

Comment: yes it seems to be working but now I am getting this error about the  shape. ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (348,27) into shape (348,)

Comment: @Mario Maybe I was too quick, the first element is not a scalar but an array, which changes the translation. Check the edit.

Comment: Yeah I changed this but still I am getting the same shape error message

Comment: @Mario I was assuming that `p.gamma_dB_min`, `p.delta_dB_gam`, `y1` and `yn` are scalars. If they're not, please include their definition in your post. Neither your MATLAB code nor your Python code are complete programs, so all we can do here is guess.

Comment: yeah the problem is y1 and yn it is generalized other two are equal to -6 and 2 respectively.

Comment: I am getting some results with this error ... TypeError: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got 'array([[ 4.751556  ],
       [ 6.0979795 ],
       [ 5.2153344 ],..... when I changed this line to  'y = np.array([(y2-y1)/N*n+y1],[y2])'

Comment: @Mario If in the MATLAB code `Y1` and `YN` are arrays, what sizes do they have? Maybe they are supposed to be row vectors? That would make `y` a matrix. Or maybe they are supposed to be column vectors with exactly `N=28` elements? Please show us how you call the MATLAB function. We need complete code to help you further. See [mre].

Comment: Since I am doing interpolation, (In mathematics, linear interpolation is a method of curve fitting using linear polynomials to construct new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points.) y1 and yn are the minimum and maximum value of this range. starting from y1 and ending on yn .

Comment: I modified the code, now this is complete code.

Comment: @Mario But what is `YTest` and `YPred`? Please substitute some bogus data with the same sizes/types as the actual data. You can use `randn()` for example to generate bogus data.

Comment: ytest and ypred  are the predicted and target values of our  machine learning model

Comment: @Mario I don't care what they mean, I care what type they are (presumably `double`?), and what sizes (horizontal 1D array? vertical 1D array? 2D array? 3D array? ...)

Comment: numpy.ndarray each of size (350,1)